# if else not work in Swift @IBaction UserDefault for checking login

Tags: ios, swift, oop, extension-methods, xcode11

I was confused.

it's because, my control flow is not work as should be.

I think, it's just basic logic. But, oddly enough, my control flow not as what I want to be.

This is my code.

[image]

which is, isLogin() method, have this code:

[image]

the oddly is why the control flow always go to if statement, even the user not yet to login.

**NB: If user not already to login, the current view must be present LoginViewController.**

anyone can to explain this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Userdfaults returns nil when it has no value.

Add nil instead of empty quotes:-

```
    if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token") != nil {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

UserDefaults returns nil if there is no value for "token"
so check that value not equal to nil

```
func isLogin()->Bool{
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    guard let token = defaults.string(forKey: "token") else{
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: and when you logout you can set nil to the key "token".

Answer (score 0):

string(forKey: "token") is optional because can return and nil when it has no value, '*isEmpty*' method checks when the string is empty or not!

```
func isLogin() -> Bool {
    let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token")
    return token != nil && !token!.isEmpty
}
```